# How do I avoid going past the end of my animation in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, animate

I would like to animate some overlays using animatevalue, but I don't know of a way to stop the animation at the last overlay.  Is there a way to make this independent of OS and pdf reader?  If not, how do you do it in whatever reader it can be done in (I suspect only Adobe Reader does it, but I don't know for sure.).

Here is a minimal example of what I want to animate and stop right before the second frame.

```
\documentclass[12pt,t]{beamer}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pstex,.eps,.ps,.pdf,.png,.jpeg,.jpg}
\setbeameroption{hide notes}
%\usetheme{default}
%\useinnertheme{default}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \raisebox{5pt}{\makebox[\paperwidth]{\hfill\makebox[20pt]{\color{gray}
          \scriptsize\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}}}\hspace*{5pt}}
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}
\begin{document}
\newlength\ciscowidth
\begin{frame}
  \animate<2-35>
  \animatevalue<1-35>{\ciscowidth}{0.7\textwidth}{0.2\textwidth}
  \frametitle{``Layered'' Data Centre}
\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{R}{\ciscowidth}%\ciscowidth}
  %\includegraphics[width=\ciscowidth]{cisco-layered.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
~\uncover<36->{
Here is a bunch of text 
Here is a bunch of text 
Here is a bunch of text 
Here is a bunch of text 
Here is a bunch of text 
Here is a bunch of text 
Here is a bunch of text 
Here is a bunch of text 
Here is a bunch of text 
Here is a bunch of text 
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Another frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does stop before second frame for me with adobe reader. Is there anything missing?

Comment: In adobe reader on the mac it does not even appear to animate...  But it's good to know that I used the \animate tag correctly.  What system did you use? edit: I take that back.  It does animate in AR full screen mode, but then I can't go back to the beginning of the first frame!  Hence the reason why I (many of us, in fact) don't use or trust it.  Can anyone suggest another pdf reader that will behave more reasonably?

Comment: This won't compile since we don't have access to your image file `cisco-layered.jpg`, cf. [how to make a minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: It should compile now :)